# One Test Method Covering Multiple If-Else Conditions

Tags: apex, unit-test

Can I cover multiple conditions in just one apex test method?

Comment: The key term in `Unit Testing` is *unit*. Test one unit per `testMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By creating a list of test records satisfying all conditions.

See below example..

```
Account ac1 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'India') ; 
Account ac2 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'AUSTRALIA') ; 
Account ac3 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'UNITED STATES') ; 
List<Account> AccountLIst = New List <Account>(); AccountLIst.add(ac1); 
AccountLIst.add(ac2); AccountLIst.add(ac3);
 try{ 
     insert AccountLIst; 
 }catch(exception e){ 
   system.assert(false,e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: do you have any sample of a single test method covering multiple conditions?

Comment: There are 100s of such example . Hold on , I will send something useful .

Comment: Account ac1 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'India') ;
Account ac2 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'AUSTRALIA') ;
Account ac3 = new Account(name ='Test Account1 ',Country__c = 'UNITED STATES') ;
List<Account> AccountLIst = New List <Account>();
AccountLIst.add(ac1);
AccountLIst.add(ac2);
AccountLIst.add(ac3);

        try{
         insert AccountLIst; 
        }catch(exception e){
            system.assert(false,e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: Rajeev - please edit your example into your answer - you should have the permissions to do this.